# Convert Pandas DataFrame into 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame like so:

```
  | A | B | C |
0 | 3 | e | w |
1 | 4 | f | x |
2 | 5 | g | y |
3 | 6 | h | z |
```

I'm trying to convert the DataFrame into a two-column structure that preserves the index value, like so:

```
0 | 3 |
0 | e |
0 | w |
1 | 4 |
1 | f |
1 | x |
2 | 5 |
2 | g |
2 | y |
3 | 6 |
3 | h |
3 | z |
```

I've tried using `df.melt` but it doesn't seem to do what I need. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df.stack().reset_index(level=1,drop=True) # df.stack().droplevel(1)

0    3
0    e
0    w
1    4
1    f
1    x
2    5
2    g
2    y
3    6
3    h
3    z
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use `melt` with `sort_index`:

```
>>> df.melt(ignore_index=False).sort_index()['value']
0    3
0    e
0    w
1    4
1    f
1    x
2    5
2    g
2    y
3    6
3    h
3    z
Name: value, dtype: object
```

Or with `stack`:

```
>>> df.stack().droplevel(1)
0    3
0    e
0    w
1    4
1    f
1    x
2    5
2    g
2    y
3    6
3    h
3    z
dtype: object
```